# Button toggle with javascript into js function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to build a page in which two buttons and a text-menu will be displayed.
By pressing the buttons the text should change into a different text-menu.
I have done that so far, the problem is that I cannot add my whole designed text into  my js function. What can I do? The idea is something like toggle switch with different texts. Thanks in advance.

```
function before(){
        document.getElementById('message')
        .innerHTML="456j";
    }
     
    function after(){
        document.getElementById('message')
        .innerHTML="hhh";
    }
```

Here is my whole code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .btn {
      border: 3px solid #f7a600;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 10px;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      transition: margin-right 2s .5s;
      ;
    }
    
    input[type="radio"].toggle {
      display: none;
    }
    
    #button1 {
      background-color: #f7a600;
      color: #ffffff;
      position: center;
      text-align: center;
      margin: auto;
      font-size: 1.8rem;
    }
    
    #button1:hover {
      background-color: #009acb;
      border-color: #009acb;
    }
    
    #button2 {
      background-color: #009acb;
      border-color: #009ACB;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 1.8rem;
    }
    
    #button2:hover {
      background-color: #f7a600;
      border-color: #f7a600;
    }
    
    .buttoncenter1 {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .buttoncenter2 {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .accordion {
      font-family: default;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: #F7A600;
      color: #ffffff;
      padding: 18px;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      text-align: left;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 26px;
      transition: 0.4s;
      font-family: 'Ubuntu';
    }
    
    .active,
    .accordion:hover {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      color: #F7A600;
    }
    
    .accordion:after {
      content: '\23F7';
      font-weight: bold;
      float: float;
      margin-left: 15px;
    }
    
    .active:after,
    .accordion {
      content: "\23F6";
    }
    
    .accordion2.active {
      color: #F7A600;
    }
    
    .accordion2 {
      font-family: default;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: #009ACB;
      color: #ffffff;
      padding: 18px;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      text-align: left;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 26px;
      transition: 0.4s;
      font-family: 'Ubuntu';
    }
    
    .active,
    .accordion2:hover {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      color: #009ACB;
    }
    
    .accordion2:after {
      content: '\23F7';
      font-weight: bold;
      float: float;
      margin-left: 5px;
    }
    
    .active:after,
    .accordion2 {
      content: "\23F6";
    }
    
    .panel-1 {
      padding: 0 18px;
      background-color: white;
      color: #424241;
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-family: 'Ubuntu';
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="switch">

    <label for="toggle-on" class="btn" onclick=before();>Όλες οι θέσεις</label>


    <label for="toggle-off" class="btn" onclick=after();>Διαθέσιμες θέσεις</label>

    <h1 id="message">
      ssddff
    </h1>
  </div>





  <button class="accordion">Αναλυτής Μέσων Κοινωνικής Δικτύωσης</button>
  <div class="panel-1">
    <p>Στα κύρια καθήκοντα συμπεριλαμβάνονται:

      <br><br>
      <ul>
        <li>
          Αναζήτηση νέων χρήσιμων social media και πλατφορμών προώθησης των δραστηριοτήτων του σωματείου

        </li>
      </ul>
      <br>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion2">Διαχειριστής Αιτημάτων </button>
  <div class="panel-1">
    <p>Στα κύρια καθήκοντα συμπεριλαμβάνονται:

      <br><br>
      <ul>
        <li>
          Καταγραφή συχνών ερωταπαντήσεων σχετικών με τη ΔΕΠΥ</li>
        <li>Καταγραφή των προβλημάτων ασθενών με ΔΕΠΥ στην Ελλάδα
        </li>
        <li>Ανάληψη τηλεφωνικής γραμμής του σωματείου
        </li>
      </ul>
      <br>

  </div>


  <button class="accordion">Επιμελητής Εθελοντικού Ανθρώπινου Δυναμικού</button>
  <div class="panel-1">
    <p>Στα κύρια καθήκοντα συμπεριλαμβάνονται:

      <br><br>
      <ul>
        <li>
          Ανάρτηση αγγελιών για προσέλκυση εθελοντών</li>
        <li>Εύρεση πλατφορμών & ομάδων για αναζήτηση εθελοντών
        </li>
      </ul>
      <br>
  </div>




  <button class="accordion2">Επιμελητής Ιδιωτικών Συνεργασιών </button>
  <div class="panel-1">
    <p>Στα κύρια καθήκοντα συμπεριλαμβάνονται:

      <br><br>
      <ul>
        <li>
          Εύρεση επαγγελματιών που θα διαφημίζονται στην ιστοσελίδα του ADHD Hellas.
        </li>
      </ul>
      <br>

  </div>



  <script>
    function before() {
      document.getElementById('message')
        .innerHTML = "456j";
    }

    function after() {
      document.getElementById('message')
        .innerHTML = "hhh";
    }






    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
          panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
      });
    }

    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion2");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
          panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
      });
    }
  </script>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry but what have you changed exaclty?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the current value of button via event.target (it would be your label element) and assign the value of it in your desired element.

```
function toggleText(event) {
    const target = event.target
    const el = document.getElementById('message')
    el.innerHTML = target.innerHTML
}

   <label for="toggle-on" class="btn" onclick=toggleText(this);>Όλες οι θέσεις</label>
    <label for="toggle-off" class="btn" onclick=toggleText(this);>Διαθέσιμες θέσεις</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but what do you mean by assigining the value to my desired item? I have not understood that part. Could you post an example? Thanks.